# Error while converting vb 6 code to vb.net

Tags: vb.net

While Running the following Function a runtime errors occurs:

```
Public Sub SelectComboItemByValue(ByRef cboorlstCntrl As Object, ByRef lngItemValue As Long)
    Dim cntrl As Control
    Dim intcounter As Integer

    cntrl = cboorlstCntrl
    For intcounter = 0 To cntrl.list.items.count - 1
        If cntrl.itemdata(intcounter) = lngItemValue Then
            cntrl.selectedindex = intcounter
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    cboorlstCntrl = cntrl

End Sub
```

Comment: Which type of an error? I mean, what message are you getting from the IDE?

Comment: In that for loop cntrl.list shows an errror that list is not a member of .control

Comment: Also itemdata and selectedindex both are showing not a member of .control

Comment: Actually i am trying to convert a vb6 code to vb.net code

Comment: Is the control a List? Why not declared it as a list directly instead of Object? And I am not sure but I don't think you should be adding the `.list`, just the `.item()` should do.

Comment: No Actually I wants to taken the items in the combobox with Its Itemdata

Comment: I am creating a dll for selecting the items in comboxes.

Comment: Have you tried casting cntrl to the proper type?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your `cntrl` as a `ComboBox`, and cast your `cboorlstCntrl` parameter into it, as in the following:

```
If TypeOf(cboorlstCntrl) Is ComboBox Then
    Dim cntrl As ComboBox = DirectCast(cboorlstCntrl, ComboBox)
    Dim intcounter As Integer

    cntrl = cboorlstCntrl
    For intcounter = 0 To cntrl.Items.Count - 1
        If cntrl.Items(intcounter) = lngItemValue Then
            cntrl.SelectedIndex = intcounter
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    cboorlstCntrl = cntrl
End If
```

By doing that, `cntrl` will have all of the methods you are expecting, such as the `.Items` property. The `.Items` property, by the way, would be the one you want to use to get the items in the control...a combo box doesn't have a `.List` property. I've updated your `For` loop to reflect this.